# Merge N arrays containing arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which contains arrays too. this array is `template`
[image]

`template` has 2 arrays, but 2 is not fixed, it can go on N number of arrays which also contains arrays. 
this is what I tried:

```
const template = health_pack_templates.map((healthpackItem, i) => {
  return healthpackItem.health_pack_templates
});
console.log('template', template);
var c = [];
  for (var i = 0; i >= template.length; i++) {
      c.push.apply(template[i]);
  }
console.log('c',c)
```

`c` does only returns `[]` and not an array with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 arrays inside. What am I doing wrong?

what I want to happen should be like this: [array 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] after it is merged.

Comment: What does `apply` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `flat()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

> The **flat()** method which creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated
>   into it recursively up to the specified depth.

Comment: @eibersji welcome!. Also, check alternatives [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because you wrote i>=template.length. it should brake your for loop immediately.

Answer (score 0):

## Merge N Arrays

There are multiple ways in javascript today to merge variable number of arrays

#### Option 1 is to use reduce:

```
let arrs = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
arrs.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
```

This is a slow solution (quadratic time).

#### Option 2 is that you can use Lodash:

```
_.flatten
```

This merges n arrays, and does it more efficiently (linear time).

#### Option 3 is to use concat function on array of arrays:

```
[].concat(...arrs);
```

Which should be efficient (linear time).

#### Option 4 is to use .flat()

```
[...arrs].flat()
```

If there are more than 1 level of nested arrays you might need to use [...arrs].flat(2) and so on

```
let arrs = [[1, 2], [3, [7, 8], 4], [5, 6]];
[...arrs].flat(2)
```